# Help me understand this: $ Pr(T < t \mid y) = \int_{0}^{\infty }\int_{\Omega }k(x)p(t, x\mid y)\,dx\,dt \ $?

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

How do I read this equation (especially the left side) in terms of a Continuous Markov Process model?

$$
Pr(T < t \mid y) = \int_{0}^{\infty }\int_{\Omega }k(x)p(t, x\mid y)\,dx\,dt \\
$$
Where $ p(t,x) $ is the transition probability density of a diffusion process, and $ y $, I assume, is the previous state of $ x $.

Is the left hand side strictly a function of $ t $? I suspect yes but...

Is the $ p( \  \mid y) $ notation necessary ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

==========================================================================

Here is an example:

Diffusion Equation: 
$$ dx=\mu dt + \sigma dW \ Eq. 1\\ $$
PDF of the diffusion:
$$ p(t,x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-t\mu )^{2}}{2\sigma t^{2}}}}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sqrt{t\sigma ^{2}}} \ Eq. 2 \\ $$
Killing function: 
$$ k(x)=\lambda x^{2} \ Eq. 3$$
$$ k(x)=\lambda x^{2}\Rightarrow T = \lambda x^{2}\Rightarrow x = \sqrt{\frac{t}{\lambda }} \\ $$
The original equations PDF (Integrated w/Mthematica):
$$ Pr(T < t, \tau  > T \mid y) =
\int_{0}^{t}\int_{\Omega }k(x)p(t, x)\,dx\,dt =
\frac{1}{6}\lambda \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^{2}t}}t^{2}\sqrt{\sigma ^{2}t}(3\sigma ^{2}+2\mu ^{2}t) \ Eq. 4 \\ $$

For some arbitrary values:
$$ \mu=0.05, \ \sigma=0.5 $$

Plotting with $ \lambda=0.5 $: 
[image]
[image]

Plotting with $ \lambda=0.01 $:
[image]
[image]

{Axes: t=horizontal, x=vertical}

So, when $ \lambda $ is larger - more paths are being killed; hence, "LHS CDF" increases much faster.

Nevertheless, the LHS PDF fully integrated does not equal 1 so its not a distribution. How to make sense of all this?

Comment: Interestingly, this was already asked and answered on the math.se site http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546691, where it was mentioned that the LHS $P(T<t\mid y)$ should actually be $P(T<\tau\mid y)$ where $\tau$ is an independent random time.

Comment: Yes, indeed - the thread clarified that I was dealing with two different density functions. Thank you for your comments. Nevertheless, I am still not convinced about the following conclusion, which is the reason I have not updated this post:                                                                                                 The Transition Probability Function defined as:
$$ p(x,t)dx=P(x(t)\in(x,x+dx),T>t) $$

Comment: ... is obtained by solving the Backward Kolmogorov PDE:
$$ \frac{\partial p(x, t)}{\partial t} = -k(x)p(x, t) + \frac{\partial\mu p(x, t)}{\partial x}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}\sigma p(x, t)}{\partial x^{2}} \\
p(x, 0) = \delta (x-x_{0}) $$
$$and \ BCs $$
... Inference:
$$ Pr(T \leq t, X \leq x) =
\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty }^{x}k(x)p(t, x)\,dx\,dt $$

Comment: Further clarification which I gathered after I made that post:                                          $ T $ is the random variable that describes the probability of the paths that are not yet killed by a certain time, $ t $ is the time value of the process, and $ \tau $ is the absorption time (the paths that are not killed, eventually get absorbed).

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional probability. You should try to understand the left part before the right part.

In the left part, it says "what's the probability of your random variable t is greater than a constant T given that you know the previous states

For example, if you want to predict the probability next raining day after next weekend and you know the history of weather. y would be the information of the weather data, t would be the random variable for the next raining day and T is the next weekend. The (|y) information is absolutely essential, your predicted probability of the next raining day given that you know the history is not the same as your prediction without knowing the history. For example, you can safely assume the probability is zero if you live in the drought area.

Unless you're comfortable with the concept of conditional probability, I wouldn't be too concern with the right part of the formula. Essentially it says "integrate and sum up all the probability over the two dimensions: time and states".

Answer (score 0):

I would read the left side of that equation as "the probability that the random variable T is less than the specific value t (which is in the domain of T) given that you know y." From what I remember, the left side is actually a function of y because, as the right side of the equation indicates, the t's are integrated out.

Maybe, in terms of the Markov Process, read the T as the time or steps to convergence given that you are at time y, or that you have come y steps. Notice that the domain of t on the right side is from zero to infinity. So, by integrating over all future times or steps, you are finding the probability that you converge before t over all the states available in the domain of x.

Comment: T is not a random variable, it's a a constant.

Comment: Really? I think I've always seen capitals representing random variables and lower case representing specific instances of the variable. In reading your answer, I think we have the same idea for the variables but are representing them differently. So, which ever way works for me.

Comment: Please look at the example I added above. Also, I believe $ T $ is a random variable. I been thinking that the first hitting time distribution is related to this very same perspective.